# .htaccess Show index regardless of URL address

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://admin.domain.com/index.html is the only page available however on this page I use `history.pushState()` so it can be changed any of the following and more:

- http://admin.domain.com/Account/Settings/General
- http://admin.domain.com/Account/Messages/Inbox
- http://admin.domain.com/Work-Station/Schedule/Clocks
- http://admin.domain.com/Work-Station/Tasks/My-Tasks

I also wish never to display `index.html` start at `/Dashboard`.

Is it possible using the .htaccess file to always display index.html (or PHP if required) re

---

gardless of what the URL is requesting?

### Error I'm Receiving With Answer Suggestions

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at to inform them of the time
>   this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

### Just got it working!

```
RewriteRule ^(Pages) - [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible using the .htaccess file to always display index.html (or PHP if required) regardless of what the URL is requesting?

Yes you can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove /index.html if entered directly in URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.html$|Pages)(.*)$ index.html?path=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I get a **Internal Server Error** *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.* when trying to access [this page](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/Account/Dashboard), here is my [index.html page](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/) which now all you seem to need to enter is the domain and if you add `index.html` it removes.

Comment: Try clicking on any of the side menu items which have no more drops available to see the pushState change the URL and then try to reload the page with that URL to see the error.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that if you enter for example "http://admin.domain.com/Work-Station/Schedule/Clocks" then the index page is shown.

Comment: Yes, it's in the same place, going to `domain.com/index.html` removes the `index.html` part. I'm with [1&1](https://www.1and1.co.uk/) and don't have a clue about apache configuration...

Comment: Just updated my question with the error I see on the page, still the same error as previously

Comment: That is the error displayed in browser and is pretty much useless. You will need to contact the support guys and find out where the Apache error.log is. Only log entries in error.log can tell you what is causing 500 error.

Comment: I've contacted them and I'll keep you posted as when I hear back from them. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Not heard back at the moment, however I've got it working, please see my updated answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your edited question.  However your question doesn't mention anywhere why `/Pages` should be skipped from this rule.

Comment: you can remove that from my question edit if you wish, it still has the same output I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the .htaccess I use for redirecting everything to a singular point

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure your Apache Conf file has

```
AllowOverride = All
```

set for the /var/www/html/ directory, or if you're using vhost set it to the /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html.

Comment: Please see the first three comments on the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41771918/6410837), your answer has the same result.

Comment: Editted my answer; It may be your apache configuration not allowing the over write.

Comment: I'm with [1&1](https://www.1and1.co.uk/) and don't have a clue about apache configuration...